# bash regexp for cleaning some chars

Tags: regex, bash, sanitize

I have a string to match and sanitize in bash, for example:

```
POST_DATA="password=this*pass&is/for?testing"
```

I want to match all the string after the = symbol sanitizing (excluding) this chars *&/?

I can get everything after the = symbol using:

```
[[ ${POST_DATA} =~ ^password=(.*)$ ]] && password="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo $password
```

This shows:

```
this*pass&is/for?testing
```

I want a regexp which desired output is:

```
thispassisfortesting
```

I tried some excluding patterns which didn't work like this:

```
^password=(^[^\*\?&/])*$
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter expansion rather than regexes:

```
#!/bin/bash
POST_DATA="password=this*pass&is/for?testing"
after_eq=${POST_DATA#*=}             # remove everything up to the first =
printf '%s\n' "${after_eq//[*&\/?]}" # remove all asterisks, ampersands, slashes and question marks
```

Comment: Maybe use `printf` - this code could fail with `echo` if the password begins with a dash.

Comment: I need it using pure bash. This is ok for me. Thank you.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis: `printf` is a bash builtin.

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
% echo "$POST_DATA" | perl -pe 's/(?:password=|[*&\/?])//g'              
thispassisfortesting
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that regular expressions are supposed to match something. You write a pattern, it either matches something or it does not. It is not supposed to remove things, only to match.

So, what you are trying to do, which is remove some specific characters in order to sanitize a string, is NOT a use case for regular expressions.
What you need is some kind of String.replace(/[^*\?&/]/, "") that will remove all the offending characters from your string.

Assuming you're working in PHP (based on the `${POST_DATA}` you used), I would suggest using: `preg_replace('/[^\*\?&\/]/','',${POST_DATA})` before matching the `password=` so that all offending characters are removed.